# Windows 10 100% disk usage after partition

Tags: partitioning, windows-10

I have a 1TB SSHD in my laptop which I just partitioned 150GB of to use as a Fedora install. However after installing it and then booting back into windows I get 100% disk usage and it seems to be maxing out at about 10Mb/s read and write to the disk.

If anyone has any idea how to fix this issue I'd appreciate the answer.

Comment: Is it still running constantly? Can you find what process is doing the read/write? Maybe windows is doing some chkdsk in the background (or even defragment).